# php encode json array

Tags: php, json, post, encode

How would I post this json encode in php. My encode post will not post anything past the company variable, I am trying to get defaultPhoneNbr to post but it will not. I think I need some sort of multiple array post but then I get an error about can't read serialized

```
$array                     = array();
$array['defaultPhoneType'] = 'Site';
$array['defaultPhoneNbr']  = '2223334444';
$array['firstname']        = 'test firstname';
$array['lastname']         = 'test lastname';

$data = json_encode($array);

array(16) {
    [0] => array(19) {
        ["id"]        => int(2)
        ["firstName"] => string(5) "Sales"
        ["lastName"]  => string(12) "Lastname"
        ["company"]   => array(4) {
            ["id"]         => int(19296)
            ["identifier"] => string(11) "Sales"
            ["name"]       => string(11) "Sales Lastname"
            ["_info"]      => array(2) {
                ["company_href"] => string(78) "/apis/3.0/company/companies/19296"
                ["mobileGuid"]   => string(36) "12413b96-c658-49a1-a182-8486e52d6160"
            }
        }
        ["site"] => array(3) {
            ["id"]    => int(1001)
            ["name"]  => string(4) "Main"
            ["_info"] => array(2) {
                ["site_href"]  => string(89) "/apis/3.0/company/companies/19296/sites/1001"
                ["mobileGuid"] => string(36) "857e1a15-6b2d-42f1-839e-5390a0bf018e"
            }
        }
        ["inactiveFlag"]       => bool(false)
        ["title"]              => string(10) "Sales Team"
        ["marriedFlag"]        => bool(false)
        ["childrenFlag"]       => bool(false)
        ["unsubscribeFlag"]    => bool(false)
        ["mobileGuid"]         => string(36) "08217845-f062-460a-8521-1c0d682a08a0"
        ["defaultPhoneType"]   => string(4) "Site"
        ["defaultPhoneNbr"]    => string(10) "6105551212"
        ["defaultBillingFlag"] => bool(false)
        ["defaultFlag"]        => bool(false)
        ["companyLocation"]    => array(3) {
            ["id"]    => int(2)
            ["name"]  => string(10) "My Company"
            ["_info"] => array(1) {
                ["location_href"] => string(73) "/apis/3.0/system/locations/2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Kindly post your expected output.

Comment: Can you write your error and complete code ?

Comment: Add Error Details and your full Code!

Comment: You need to go learn how to ask a proper question. Please go read [ask].

Comment: There is no error but 'defaultPhoneNbr' does not post to this rest api.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out to post the phone number had to get posted to a whole different url and a separate array